# datetime column interval Select won't work

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This code won't return anything from mysql even though having 2 rows that mach my criteria , if you remove the las condition it works but I what  it not to display older than +8 hours rows, I suppose this is not reflecting my criteria on code because  no mysql error but neither does it output any rows:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City');
$not_jet = date('Y-m-d-H-i-s', time());
$ended = date('Y-m-d-H-i-s', strtotime('+8 hours'));
$str = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM evento WHERE Id_Coordinador=".$_SESSION['uid']." AND Fecha_Hora>".$not_jet." AND Fecha_Hora<".$ended." ORDER BY Categoria");
```

am trying directly on phpmyadmin :

```
SELECT * FROM evento WHERE Id_Coordinador=111390 AND Fecha_Hora > 2014-05-25-12-00-00 AND Fecha_Hora < 2014-05-25-23-00-00 ORDER BY Categoria
```

which should produce something like this

[image]

could you help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DateTime value must be enclosed in single quotes as

```
$str = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM evento 
       WHERE Id_Coordinador=".$_SESSION['uid']." 
       AND Fecha_Hora>'".$not_jet."' 
       AND Fecha_Hora<'".$ended."' ORDER BY Categoria");
```

Comment: thanks it works,  but why it works on other queries without single quotes ?

Comment: Datetime is treated as string and any string values must be enclosed within single quotes. Even if you use preparedStatement you need to bind the parameter using 's' stands for string.